# Page content extending beyond that of the window width

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, responsive

So I've been tinkering with this site, and I've got my work cut out, but right now I cannot for the life of me workout why content is displaying beyond the width of the window.

-redacted-

I believe it's something to do with bootstraps row/col guttering but have been unable to fix it, even with dreaded '!important' use.

Furthermore i note that a carousel button is extending beyond the width of the screen.

This basically just makes the site flimsy and seem broken.

Any css whizz out there able to give me some tips of this shit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is with one specific tag (e.g. a `<div>`), add a class/id to that div with the following CSS: `.classname { overflow-x: hidden;` If it's the whole page, you might want to do that for the body and HTML tag. **Note:** When you do this last thing, people aren't able at all to scroll horizontally. This is a but user unfriendly, so you want to use that only if it's the only way out in my opinion.